c++: How can I import a module partition only? (VS2022)
Suppose we have our module Utils which itself contains "submodule" Foo:
Utils.ixx:
export module Utils;

export import :Foo;

Foo.ixx:
export module Utils:Foo;

import std;

export namespace myNamespace
{
    inline void foo() { std::println("foo"); }
}

When I want to import the whole Utils module, everything is OK.
However, when I want to import Foo module only, Could not find module file for module "Utils.Foo" error pops out.
main.cpp:
import Utils; // OK
import Utils.Foo // error: Could not find module file for module 

How can I import such "submodule"?
Besides reading the documetation, I have no experience with modules, so I have no idea what I am doing wrong
I use Visual Studio 2022 latest version, with std=c++latest and modules enabled
Edit: removed my foolish std.compact (I somehow cannot read properly)

You just cannot. A module partition is a part of a module and cannot be imported separately (except from other parts of the same module). Also Utils.Foo does not name Utils:Foo, but is a totally separate module that happens to have a dot in its name.

Also, the standard modules (of C++23) are named std and std.compat. The latter is not a subset, but an extended version of std. See P2465R1

@BoP Thank you very much for your answer. So as I understand, to achieve Utils.Foo functionality I would have to rename "Foo" to "Utils.Foo"?

Changing the Foo partition to a separate module using export module Utils.Foo; would allow to import it separately. The dot in the name is allowed for namespacing purposes for developers, but has no special meaning for compilers.
Note that importing modules is much cheaper than including headers (it is compiled once), so there might be no need for extra granularity.
